# Get rid of the vertical line in the Xcode editor

Tags: xcode

For some reason I introduced a vertical line in my code editor of Xcode. How do I get rid of it? Also, why such thing exists?

[alt text http://s21.postimg.org/uuj645fsl/Screen_Shot_2015_08_09_at_11_23_42_PM.png](http://s21.postimg.org/uuj645fsl/Screen_Shot_2015_08_09_at_11_23_42_PM.png)

Comment: which vertical line are you talking about? Highlight it in your pic. Not clear.

Comment: I think he's talking about some cursor artifact (next to the "1") that occasionally appears with text editors.

Comment: Turn off the screen and turn it back on perhaps.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Could be the Inspector.

Comment: Not the inspector. It is the editor window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears from the image you posted that you've enabled the page guide.  You can turn this off by opening the Xcode `Preferences` and switching to the `Text Editing` tab.  Finally, deselect the `Page guide at column:` checkbox.